# How to view Firefox Bookmark from SSH -X?

Tags: ssh, firefox

Hello I have bookmarked a particular page on Mozilla firefox long back on my Linux machine and now I am using SSH -X from my home machine, could you please tell me how do I retrieve bookmark information from the home machine.

Much Thanks!

Comment: You could also create a Firefox account and sync the bookmarks (and more) to other computers/devices running Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

`firefox` data are stored in `~/.mozilla/firefox`. You can find the bookmarks you want in this directory. But I think the bookmark information would be stored in files of binary form. So my suggestion is to copy the whole directory with `scp` and follow this link https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles to retrieve your data in `firefox`. (Remember to backup your data of `firefox` in your home computer) After obtaining what you want, remember to change the `firefox` data back following the same methods in the above link.